# Codeigniter session expiry issue at any time

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter and i dont know that why codeigniter session is expired at any time. There is not any fixed time when its session expire. Sometimes when i dont know anything for 5 minutes and when i just reload page , then session expire.

This is terrible. Can you help me to resolve this issue ? Following settings is done in config.php file.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;
```

This does not seem works.

Comment: I this is `$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;` to change the session time to expire is this `$config['sess_expiration']  = 1440;` or what ever 7200 is 2 hours I think

Comment: some one suggest me to set 86400 instead of default 300.  But still it does not work. i have set sess_expiration=7200.  But as i said, session expire at any time (even within 5 minutes it may expire).

Comment: I think is in integer format

Comment: i am working in localhost. However i have also changed $config['encryption_key'] to different unique value.

Comment: i also notice that when i do some  change in coding then session also expire. This does not happen always. But sometimes it is done. But i dont think that there should be any issue in edit my php code.

Comment: What version Ci you using

Comment: Did you read the part down bottom here what all means http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html scroll down page

Comment: Your version is very outdated.

Comment: I had checked it. but everything seems ok as per this docs. I will try another settings and will see what happen.  thanks for your help.

Comment: $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;   Can you help us what records getting save in table ci_sessions? as use using sess_use_database

Comment: INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES
('29955a473b3eb5b4khiu%eb5a4f7b74e', '::1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36', 1474268364, 'a:3:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:14:"id_msg_user";s:1:"1";s:5:"loginuser";s:26:"admin";}');

Comment: In my php files i have some array like $detail['id'], $detail['name'], etc in one page. When i just changed array name from $detail to $other_request_detail. Then on reload page session was expired. I dont know why session expire if change my variable in coding. There should not any relation with session module of CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with, when you set 0 it will never expire.

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
```

And another thing about encryption_key,

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '!$W3nCrYp+!0nK3y';
```

You can change your unique key as same or with another keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check my post here [CodeIgniter unexpected session rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788313/codeigniter-unexpected-session-rotation)

You need to check a function called "sess_gc" in Session.php. The sess_gc function will delete all of the session records once it is triggered. That means, someone else can reset your session. You can comment out the function or add some delay when it delete records.